# how to Share model object in @RequestMapping methods in spring mvc without using session?

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using Spring to create and download Excel sheet I want to add some  variable in model in requestiong mapping method so that I can use in other request maping method

```
@RequestMapping("/contentUploadDetails/{content_type}/{date}")
public ModelAndView contentUpload(
        @PathVariable(value = "content_type") String content_type,
        @PathVariable(value = "date") String date) {
  List<CountAndValue> ls = contentCountImp
            .getuploadedContentCountDatewise(content_type, date);
    model.addObject("CountAndValue", ls);
    return model;
}
```

As you can see in above

```
 model.addObject("CountAndValue", ls);
```

I want to use this model value  in my other requestMapping method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ContentUploadExport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getExcel() {

    return new ModelAndView("CountAndValueExcel", "CountAndValue", CountAndValue);
}
```

how can I use CountAndValueExcel model object that is set by first method in second method with using session? Can I send model object(which contains list of class object) back from view to controller?

Comment: Assuming you are redirecting from one controller to another, you can use flash attributes, checkout  - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-flash-attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can save an object into a session:

```
@RequestMapping("/contentUploadDetails/{content_type}/{date}")
public ModelAndView contentUpload(HttpServletRequest request,
        @PathVariable(value = "content_type") String content_type,
        @PathVariable(value = "date") String date) {
  List<CountAndValue> ls = contentCountImp
            .getuploadedContentCountDatewise(content_type, date);
    model.addObject("CountAndValue", ls);
    request.getSesion().setAttribute("CountAndValue", ls);
    return model;
}
```

And then you retrieve it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ContentUploadExport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getExcel(HttpServletRequest request) {
    List<CountAndValue> CountAndValue = (List<CountAndValue>) request.getSession().getAttribute("CountAndValue");
    return new ModelAndView("CountAndValueExcel", "CountAndValue", CountAndValue);
}
```

Wrote it from my head, not tested.

Comment: thanx for the reply i have already done it with session its working but there any other way if dnt want to use session variable

Comment: I'm afraid not since you can't preserve state between two requests without using an object on the server side. It could also be something custom made, but the best way is to go with sessions. I'm also not a big fan of sessions but sometimes there is no other way for a certain problem. Maybe it could also be a design issue, can't tell without deeper insight into the use case.